# Why is the narrator the one leaving in "Streets of Gold"?

Tags: song-lyrics, needtobreathe

The song *Streets of Gold* by Needtobreathe contains the following lyrics:

> I  want you to know
> **I'm leaving to let you go**
> And someday we'll walk upon
> The streets of gold
> I don't remember seeing fear in your eyes
> When you were fading
> The day we said our goodbyes
> ...
> Running through your veins was a slow-ticking clock
> Counting down the days
> And no one could make it stop

The narrator appears to be referring to someone who is near the end of their life. However, the narrator says that *he's* "leaving to let you go." Why does the narrator say that he's the one that's leaving?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The narrator is leaving to let his loved one die peacefully

<sub>For the purposes of this answer, “narrator” refers to the singer and “loved one” refers to the subject of the song.</sub>

The narrator knows that his loved one isn’t afraid of death.

> I don't remember seeing fear in your eyes
> When you were fading
> The day we said our goodbyes

His loved one is ready to die - there is no "fear in [their] eyes" while they are "fading" away or saying "goodbyes". The narrator sings about his difficulty coming to terms with this inevitability:

> It's easy to say that there's a reason for this
> Much harder to know
> That what we say is true
> Everything we hold could someday slip away

The narrator acknowledges that simply saying “there’s a reason for this” is easy to say but harder to take comfort in. It’s difficult to believe that such comforts are true when a loved one is dying in front of you. He realizes how “[e]verything we hold could someday slip away”.

And yet, even though letting go is hard, the narrator sings about how he believes his loved one will go to a better place:

> I've got a feeling I'm gonna find you again
> Just in a place where love can’t die

So the narrator resolves not to try to keep his loved one in this world. He realizes that even though it is hard, he must let his loved one go. Therefore he is  “leaving to let [them] go” . This is explicitly outlined in the chorus:

> I want you to know
> I'm leaving to let you go
> And someday we'll walk upon
> The streets of gold

He is leaving, allowing his loved one to go to a better place. “Someday” the narrator will join them there, in that better place with “streets of gold”.

Therefore, the narrator specifically is leaving to allow his loved one to pass peacefully to a better place.

All quotes from [this page](https://genius.com/Needtobreathe-streets-of-gold-lyrics)